# I can import matplotlib.pyplot in one file.py but I cannot import it in view.py in django app

Tags: python, django, matplotlib

I have plot_file.py which has:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_graph():
    squares = [1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
    plt.plot(squares)
    plt.savefig('static/img/sqaure_plot.png', bbox_inches='tight')
```

When I run this, it works and saves the file correctly. I am trying to import this function in the views.py within the same app folder in Django.

When I put the import statement in the views.py

```
from myapp.plot_file import plot_graph as pg
```

And save it and try to initiate runserver from the terminal I get:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'
```

Both the files are in the same folder

```
myapp/plot_file.py
myapp/views.py
```

I have installed matplotlib using pip3 install matplotlib. I am using MacOS with python3 installed later. I am using Sublime Text which is compiling on Python3.

I do not understand how I can import matplotlib in plot_file.py and not in the views.py file?

Beginner here. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
from plot_file.py import plot_graph as pg
```

should be

```
from plot_file import plot_graph as pg
```

or

```
import plot_file.plot_graph as pg
```

and make sure you have `__init__.py` file in your `myapp` folder

Comment: I have __init__.py in myapp folder. When I put from plot_file import plot_graph as pg or import plot_file.plot_graph as pg it says, NoModuleNamed plot_file. I put from myapp.plot_file import plot_graph as pg, it gives NoModuleNamed 'matplotlib' @Exprator

Comment: try with `myapp.plot_file` if it doesnt work use `project_name.myapp.plot_file`

Comment: Tried myapp.plot_file, it says ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib' @Exprator

Comment: can you rename your file to something else rather than plot_file. maybe graph_file and import it. i guess the plot name is making some issue

Comment: It gives the same error when named graph_file as well. ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'. Even if I just put 'import matplotlib.pyplot as plt' in views.py I get this error when I initiate runserver. Do I need to separately install matplotlib in django env or app? @Exprator